# Como pegar a primeira palavra de uma string com jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

Ex.: "Primeira palavra da string"

Quero pegar a palavra "Primeira"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Na realidade nem precisas de jQuery, "com jQuery" seria igual:

```js
var strg = 'Primeira palavra da string';
var word_one = strg.split(' ')[0];// separar str por espaços
console.log(word_one);
```

Comment: `+1` também! :)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: De nada @CaiqueSouza

Comment: [-1 not enough jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: @VictorStafusa hehe

Answer (score 6):

Uma maneira bem simples é pegar a posição do espaço com `indexOf` e extrair com `substring`:

```
primeira = texto.substring(0, texto.indexOf(" "));
```

Demonstração:

```js
var texto = "Teste de extração com espaço";
var primeira = texto.substring(0, texto.indexOf(" "));

console.log( primeira );
```

E aqui um pequeno truque para não vir vazio o resultado, caso seja uma palavra sem espaços:

```js
var texto = "Teste";
var primeira = texto.substring(0, (texto + " ").indexOf(" "));

console.log( primeira );
```

Trocando o `texto.indexOf(" ")` por `(texto + " ").indexOf(" ")` nós garantimos sempre um espaço no final do teste, para resolver o caso da palavra única.

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer isso partindo a frase em pedaços e usando `.shift()`.

```js
var strg = 'Primeira palavra da string';
var word_one = strg.split(' ').shift();
console.log(word_one);
```

Ou via expressão regular e usando `.shift()`.

```js
var strg = 'Primeira palavra da string';
var word_one = strg.match(/^[^\s]+/).shift();
console.log(word_one);
```

Comment: Sempre em grande (: +1, nem me lembrei do `.shift()`

Answer (score 2):

Uma sugestão para caso o texto comece com espaços é usar o método [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) antes de separar a string.

```js
var str = '  Primeira palavra da string';
var primeira = str.trim().split(' ')[0];
console.log(primeira);
```